# TTF triples are recollements

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, triangulated-categories

The notion of [recollement](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/recollement) 
$$
\mathcal{A}' 
    \stackrel{\overset{i^*}{\longleftarrow}}{\stackrel{\overset{i_*}{\longrightarrow}}{\underset{i^!}{\longleftarrow}}}
  \mathcal{A}\stackrel{\overset{j_!}{\longleftarrow}}{\stackrel{\overset{j^*}{\longrightarrow}}{\underset{j_*}{\longleftarrow}}}\mathcal{A}''
$$
introduced in Beilinson-Bernstein-Deligne "Faisceaux Pervers" is well known to admit an equivalent reformulation in terms of the so-called "TTF triples" (see for example Remark 2.14 [here](http://users.uoi.gr/abeligia/torsion.pdf), and pag. 66-67 [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0801.0507)), i.e. with triples of subcategories of $\cal A$, $(\mathcal X, \cal Y, Z)$ such that both $(\cal X, Y)$ and $(\cal Y, Z)$ are torsion theories (=t-structures) on $\cal A$.

> Is there a "reliable" and "elementary" source where this correspondence is shown to be the object-part of an equivalence of categories between a (suitable) category $\mathbf{TTF}_{\cal A}$ of TTF-triples on a fixed $\cal A$ and a (suitable) category $\mathbf{Recol}_{\cal A}$ of recollements having $\cal A$ as central object?